# How to redirect a Google search result to a dynamic Web page?

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-data, google-base

I'm trying to enter a list of items into [Google Base](http://www.google.com/base/?gsessionid=4zzSowZKNrT4MlmWGPr7jA) via an XML feed so that, when a user searches for one of these items and then clicks the search result link in Google Base (or plain Google), the user is directed to a dynamic Web page on my Web site. I'm assuming that the only way to specify a specific link (either static or dynamic) is through the  attribute in the XML feed. Is that correct? So, for example, if my  attribute is:

```
http://www.example.com/product1-info.html
```

the user will be directed to the `product1-info.html` page.

But if, instead of a static product page, I want to have the user redirected to a dynamic page that generates search results from my local database (on my Web site) for all products containing the keyword "product1", would I be able to do something like this?:

```
http://www.example.com/products.php?productID=product1
```

Finally, and most importantly, is there any way to specify this landing page (or any specific landing page) from a "regular" Google search? Or is it only possible via Google Base and the  attribute? In other words, if I put a bunch of stuff into Google Base, if any of it shows up in a regular Google search, is there a way for me to control what parameters get passed to the landing page (and thus, what search is performed on the landing page), or is that out of my control? I hope I explained this correctly. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first question: Yes, urls containing a query_string part are allowed.
http://base.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78170 says:

```
XML example:
<link>http://www.example.com/asp/sp.asp?cat=12&amp;id=1030</link&gt;
```

--
Let me rephrase the second question to see **if** I understand it correctly (might be completely on the wrong track): E.g. products.php?productID=product1 performs a db-search for the product "FooEx" and products.php?productID=product2 for "BarPlus". Now you want google to show the link .../products.php?productID=product1 but not ....?productId=product2 if someone searched for "FooEx" and google decided that your site is relevant? Then it's the same "problem" we all face with search engines: communicate what each url is relevant for. I.e. e.g. have the appropriate (and only the appropriate) keywords appear in the title/h1 element of the page, avoid linking to the same contents with different urls (e.g. product.php?x=1&productId=1 <-> product.php?productId=1&x1, different urls requesting most probably the exact same contents), submit a sitemap, and so on and on....

edit:
and you can avoid the query-string part all together by using something like [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (e.g. the [front controller](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.html) for the zend framework [makes use of it](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.html#zend.controller.quickstart.go.rewrite)) or by parsing the contents of $_SERVER["PATH_INFO"] (this requires the webserver [to provide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) that information), e.g. http://localhoast/test.php/foo/bar -> $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']=='/foo/bar'
Also take a look at the link to this thread: [How to redirect a Google search result to a dynamic Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940665/how-to-redirect-a-google-search-result-to-a-dynamic-web-page), it contains the title of the thread, but SO is perfectly happy with [How to redirect a Google search result to a dynamic Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940665), too. The title is "only" additional data for search engines and (even more) the user.
You can do the same:
http://www.example.com/products.php/product1/FooEx <-> http://www.example.com/products.php/product2/BarPlus